# Raspberry Pi 4B duplicate Rx pins

Tags: gpio, raspberry-pi-os

Can I duplicate Rx on raspberry? If its possible how it will be? I need to connect 2 device which connect via gpio tx/rx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is ambiguous.

Most Pi models have only 1 accessible serial port on BCM 14,15.
They have a second, which is often used for Bluetooth, but is inaccessible.

The Pi4 has 6 [UART](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697)
, although there are restrictions on which can be used.

If you want to use 2 serial devices this is not possible on a single port. You can send to as many devices as you want, but only receive on one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a serial to USB converter you can connect multiple devices via USB (as well as one via TXD/RXD).